# Firebase most recent entries show last

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to sort entries in my firebase by the most recent entry showing up as the first entry. I keep running into the issue that the most recent entry shows up last.

I am trying to sort by time as well as this is how it is set up in my databases:
[image]

I am also doing this in my code

```js
 completed.child(user.uid).orderByValue("time")
```

I was wondering where I was going wrong

This is how it shows up in my app:
**[image: strong text]**

Comment: You already sorting with time, and you want to sort with recent entities too?

Comment: I am to have the most recent time be at the time not at the bottom. Currently as it is it will always show the recent time all the way at the bottom

Comment: Can you try this at the end orderByKey()

Comment: Hey @FrankvanPuffelen, I just took a look at your answer and it was very helpful! Thank it seems the best course for this would be redo the way the time's are stored to make it easier to sort. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are quite a few problems with your code, so I'll try to address them in turn.

---

#### To order by a child property, use `orderByChild`

You're calling `orderByValue("time")`, but if you check the documentation you'll note that `orderByValue()` takes no parameters. If you want to order on the value of a child property, you should call `orderByChild("time")`.

---

#### Use a time format that allows sorting them

Your current time format is not suited for sorting it. The problem is that your lexicographical sort order doesn't match with the chronological sort order you want. More simply put, this is the sort order you'll get (but not want):

- `"6:26AM"`
- `"6:26PM"`
- `"6:27AM"`

To get the result you want, use a string format that allows the sorting. For example, use 24 hour/military notation with 0-padding:

- "06:26"
- "06:27"
- "18:26"

You could also store a numerical value, for example: the number of minutes since midnight:

- (( 6 * 60) + 26) =  386
- (( 6 * 60) + 27) =  387
- ((18 * 60) + 26) = 1106

---

#### Firebase always returns in ascending order

Firebase always returns results in ascending order. I'll recommend reading a few [relevant questions](https://www.google.com/search?q=site:stackoverflow.com+fiebase+sort+descending), but you have two options here:

1. Reverse the results client-side. This is often the simplest, as you're usually dealing with relatively a small result set.
2. Store an inverted value in the database for sorting.

This last one is typically easiest if you use a numerical value, like the number of minutes since midnight that we used above. If we store `-1 *` this value, we can then sort on that to get the results in reverse.

- -1 * (( 6 * 60) + 26) =  -386
- -1 * (( 6 * 60) + 27) =  -387
- -1 * ((18 * 60) + 26) = -1106